# Create a batch file to execute tasklist and append its output to log.txt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to execute tasklist every 3 minutes and log it into log.txt. 
I'm very new to batch files and would like to know where I've gone wrong in my batch file.

```
@echo off
set "CURRENT_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Downloads\"

:checkLog
if exist "%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt" goto writeLog
echo Log file exists. Appending data.
if not goto createLog

:createLog
echo Creating log.txt
echo   >"%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt"

:writeLog
tasklist >> "%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt"
goto loop

:loop
sleep 3 
goto writeLog
```

Comment: You define `%CURRENT_DIR%` with a backslash at the end, then refer to `"%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt"`, which results in a double backslash (wrong, but not fatal because Windows automatically resolves this)

Comment: `if not goto createLog` is wrong syntax (fatal, will stop your script). It looks like a comment to me, so use `REM if not goto createLog`

Comment: `echo   > ...` will print "echo is OFF" to the file. To write an empty line use `echo/ >>...`

Comment: `sleep` - works only with some older versions of Windows (so it *might*  be correct for your Windows version). The correct command would be `timeout` (non-fatal - will give an errormessage and continue with the script)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is unfinished:

```
if not goto createLog
```

I simplified it a little, and used `timeout` instead of `sleep`:

```
@echo off
set "CURRENT_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Downloads\"

if not exist "%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt" (
echo Creating log.txt
echo   >"%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt"
) else (
echo Log file exists. Appending data.
)

:writeLog
tasklist >> "%CURRENT_DIR%\log.txt"
timeout /t 3 > nul
goto writeLog
```

Comment: I tried this and when I opened the log file the only output there is 'Log file exists. Appending data, not the output of the tasklist command

Comment: @MichelleAshwini: **DON'T** name your script `tasklist` `:D`